# cv2.drawContours(img2,cnts,-1(0,255,0),3) TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, opencv

Here is my code ---

```
import cv2


import imutils




import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image =cv2.imread("image path")

image=imutils.resize(image,width=500)

cv2.imshow("Original Image",image)

cv2.waitKey(0)

gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow("l - Grayscale convertion",gray)

cv2.waitKey(0)

gray=cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,11,17,17)


cv2.imshow("2-Bilateral Filter",gray)

cv2.waitKey(0)

edged=cv2.Canny(gray,170,200)

cv2.imshow("3-Canny Edge",edged)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cnts,new__=cv2.findContours(edged.copy(),cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

img1=image.copy()

cv2.drawContours(img1,cnts,-1,(0,255,0),3)

cv2.imshow("4-All Contours",img1)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cnts=sorted(cnts,key=cv2.contourArea,reverse=True)[:30]


NumberPlateCnt=None

img2=image.copy()

cv2.drawContours(img2,cnts,-1(0,255,0),3)

cv2.imshw("5-Top 30 Contours",img2)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

this code is to get Characters in the numberplate [number plate image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g921h.jpg)

Comment: How about putting a comma between `-1` and `(0,255,0)` in `cv2.drawContours(img2,cnts,-1(0,255,0),3)`?

Comment: thank you soo much!!! it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add ',' after -1. And you are calling -1 as a function.

```
cv2.drawContours(img2, cnts, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```